# How to specify content inside @html.LabelFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following in the razor view:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Now I want to append the following after the models name : `<span class="asterisk">*</span>`

so that once its rendered it looks like:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2">Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
```

or possibly an alternative to this.

Maybe I can override the LabelFor method to see if that data model item has a Required metadata tag and if so, it will add the Asterisk automatically.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but why 'C' tag?

Comment: Any particular reason you "have" to use labelfor? And not just use the labelcode you already created? Unless of course you need to use the label in 1000 different places.

Comment: Merely for the reason that I can control the label name in a single place. Ie the models meta data.

Comment: @UniCell: Technically, the OP could either be using C# or VB, so if a code-based solution is needed like a helper, then that information becomes important.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override `LabelFor`, but you can add your own HtmlHelper extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RequiredIndicatorLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> modelProperty)
{
   return RequiredIndicatorLabelFor(html, modelProperty, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString RequiredIndicatorLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> modelProperty, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var htmlAttributesDict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(modelProperty, html.ViewData);

    // To just add a class to the label tag
    // if (metadata.IsRequired)
    // {
    //     var cssClass = htmlAttributesDict["class"];
    //     htmlAttributesDict["class"] = (cssClass == null) ? "required" : cssClass + " required";
    // }
    // return html.LabelFor(modelProperty, metadata.GetDisplayName(), htmlAttributesDict);

    // To add text/HTML to content of label tag
    var builder = new TagBuilder("label");
    builder.MergeAttribute("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId());
    builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributesDict);
    builder.SetInnerText(metadata.GetDisplayName());

    if (metadata.IsRequired)
    {
        var spanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        spanBuilder.AddCssClass("asterisk");
        spanBuilder.SetInnerText("*");
        builder.InnerHtml += " " + spanBuilder.ToString();
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I would build an razor helper rather than c#

Comment: Umm... no. Razor helpers are horrible. Not only is re-use a constant problem, but it violates on of the core tenets of MVC: keeping as much logic as possible out of the view.

Comment: Ummm... Let me see... But keeping the view logic outside of view, doesn't violate nothing?

Comment: It's not view logic. In fact, the whole point is that there should be no such thing as view logic. It's the whole reason the built-in helpers exist, and this is no different. The logic is encapsulated in an extension method, and the view doesn't need to know or care what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Chris I don't know if you are correct, but you seems to have a point. I will take that in mind next time I'll think if I am going to use razor helpers. I know that they are extreemly useful and easy to implement.